# What's the point of voting for winterbash hats?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash

Just out of curiosity, **why do individual sites have to make a meta post asking users to vote regarding the winterbash hats**?

Were there any cases where some sites voted against it? even if so, aren't users who hate it able to hide it with a click of a button if I remember correctly? [I hate Hats] button or something like that.

So, What's the point? why not switch it on by default and let those who hate it use that hate button?

Comment: I seem to recall that Math Overflow might have opted out, and there might have been others.

Comment: @D.W. is correct about Math Overflow - see http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/2053/winter-bash-on-mo

Comment: Because [some hats](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4356/oh-the-horror-hat-club-2013) cause "disruption" to the site (overgaming the system), and some sites don't want to have that.

Comment: Sites don't *have* to ask; some of mine went straight to "yes" based on the response to past years.  Probably some of those who ask do so because they see it elsewhere or remember it from when hats were newer.

Comment: Related: [Make the “hats” vs “no hats” choice instead “users can opt out” vs “users can opt in”](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270504/make-the-hats-vs-no-hats-choice-instead-users-can-opt-out-vs-users-can-op)

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the site community. Yeah, the *I hate hats* button can be turned off, but it wouldn't be fun when just 10-15 users are opting for the WinterBash and the rest don't.  It takes the fun out of the fest. Instead, completely opting out and staying plain is better, rather than some users getting excited on chat when a majority others are like "meh" is a bit of nuisance.

So, if the majority of the site is not in favour of hats, then it'd be a nuisance to have them just for some users.

So, *[To hat or not to hat](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3423/40657)* is the question.

Comment: Are you aware of any site where users rejected the hats by majority?

Comment: @HeidelBerGensis  AFAIK, I haven't seen any site(in which I'm active in) opting out, which adds weight to your argument.  But, in case they really want to, then the poll can help.

Comment: But, if there is none, then what's the point of voting.. that [I hate hats] button should be enough for those few who hate hats..and fun..

Comment: @HeidelBerGensis I guess the voting is trickling down as a tradition from the first fest.  Even, we at the DataScience SE didn't have a poll as the hats are on by default from last year.  So, to poll or not to poll depends on the mod  :)

Comment: ok, makes sense. But mods then have to report to SE team to chose whether to switch it on or not.. correct?

Comment: @HeidelBerGensis  Yes.  If they were *on* last year, they'd be on this year by default. So, SE have to be informed if they don't want them this year.

Comment: @HeidelBerGensis No - mods do not have to report to the SE team ***unless*** they want them turned off.

Answer (score 1):

As you will see in [my answer](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4098/115) to [Is GIS SE participating in 2015 Winter Bash Holiday Hats Promotion?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4097/115) our site opted not to hold a poll this year based on last year's poll being overwhelmingly in favour of hats.

Comment: Thats my point..

Comment: In answer to your first question, we did not make a post asking our users to vote on hats this year.

Comment: That question is not regarding a specific site, the question is why do SE in general ask sites to vote...

Comment: Perhaps re-read your bolded question which asks about individual sites and asserts that all had to make a polling post - ours didn't.