# Change "I hate hats" to an opt-in approach on ALL sites (not only on SO)

Tags: feature-request, winter-bash

---

---

## Updates:

1. For those who still don't get the real meaning of my question ... : #JeSuisBruxelles

... No matter how many extra downvotes this question will get because of this update.

2. Would be nice if that enable/disable hats-technology could be used also for indicating support for #JeSuisBruxelles (whatever the default would be).

---

---

Consider changing the logic behind "I hate hats" to an implementation with some logic to express something like "Count me in" (feel free to pick whatever label that fits) ...

That way somebody who does NOT want to participate does NOT have to go indicate something about ***"hate" ... during the time of the year that's supposed to be about "peace"***.

Moreover:

- you could use such "opt in" as a way to get your very first hat!
- I can't imagine that SE-marketeers (or whatever) would not be interested in knowing about the thousands (???) of users who pushed some related button (or whatever) as a kind of call-to-action (now they only know about those (fee?) who "do not like" hats).

And I've done my homework ... :

- "https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270504" is NOT a duplicate about this question ... IMHO ...
- "https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270833" includes "SE makes me hate" ... That's not the case for me (SE will never succeed in that ...). And it states a request like "can we choose NOT to participate", which is the opposite of what I'm suggesting here. It's like asking "where do I end up if I go North?", which can impossibly be considered as a duplicate of "where do I end up if I go South?". So this question is related, but not enough to justify closing (IMHO). It's not about changing a label, but the whole mechanism around it. A possible implementation (I guess) could be as suggested by @Shadow... which is to move this to the user profile under Preferences tab, and in the snowflake menu put something like "Change preferences" (or whatever label that does not include the word "hate").

**Note**: as per [this source](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/12/announcing-winter-bash-2015/) mentioned in one of the comments to the first answer to this question, it seems that on SO such "opt-in" approach/logic is already implemented. But "I" am not able anymore to verify (QA-test) that, since "I" originally used the approach implemented on Drupal.SE and the opt-in/opt-out choice one makes, seems to apply for all sites together (that choice itself seems to make sense to me).

Comment: I completely agree with you in this matter. Check my [comment](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/53012607#53012607) on the chat. +1.

Comment: @MauricioContreras merci for the support, and +1 ... PS: I also "do not like" chat, want to copy/paste your chat msg as extra comment here?

Comment: Sure: *Ok, here's the thing. Whitout any intention of polemize things. I'm not interested in participate of this Winter Bash thing. So, you gave me a very rude option that states that I hate hats. And that's not true. And if I want to revert that situation, you gave me the I love hats, which isn't true either.* Thnx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This option already exists, but initially only on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/), as people there by default seem to 'hate' hats. Other than that, everybody is already assumed to love them (while having the option not to do so).

This is explained in the [announcement of Winter Bash](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/12/announcing-winter-bash-2015/), just above the last picture:

> You can opt out of the event by clicking on the snowflake icon in the top bar —the Winter Bash notification is to the right of the standard notifications— and then the "I hate hats" link at the bottom left of the box that pops up. (**NB: the reverse is true on Stack Overflow; fans of hats on SO will have to go through the same procedure but click a link to opt in at the end.**)

Comment: Looks likes about a year later the same is going to come up soon again. This time I plan to FIRST go visit SO about it, hoping my preference will carry over to all other SE-sites ...

Answer (score 3):

No, I prefer the opt-out system be applied with exceptions based on individual community meta feedback.

You request, for instance, shows why this should be the case - you've only visited 5 sites in the last two weeks, and you are only very active on one site in particular - why should you, or I, or anyone - choose the default position for all communities?

The only people who have a valid standing in making this choice are the people running the site, and my understanding is that they set the default to opt-out, then let the communities decide, and now have a few years feedback demonstrating that a relatively small minority choose to opt out. Thus the majority are fine with the current situation.  In other words, they have the data to back up their choice.

If a majority choose to opt-out, or if a particular site's community chooses to default to opt-in, or ban the fun altogether, then it due to an individual site request made on that site's meta where all users can vote on it.

Make the post on the sites you're interested in changing, and see how each community wants to run the fun. If, like Stack Overflow, they make a big enough fuss and agree with you, they will be switched to opt-in.

Comment: Thanks for your answer/viewpoint Adam. I think I understand your viewpoint (and respect yours). It'd be interesting to hear from someone with a Marketing background to what extend my "marketeers"-argument would make sense to them. PS: you're probably right about the 5 sites i visited the last 2 weeks or so, but have you noticed that "yellow badge" I have on nearly all (if not all) sites that are visible to you. in other words: after lurking for about 3 quarters, I've found the sites that to me are most valueable.

Comment: *"I can't imagine that SE-marketeers (or whatever) would not be interested in knowing about the thousands (???) of users who pushed some related button"* I can.  When people get a hat, they can investigate it, or ignore it.  They can wear it, or ignore it.  They have a lot of data that indicates participation levels, as well as data that indicates irritation levels.  I don't think they are making these decisions in the blind.

Comment: Take, for example, the shear number of a site's most active contributers wearing hats: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/users  Further, I think one thing you're missing is that this is a participation incentive program, and one of the things Stack Exchange wants to do is promote participation.  Seasonal activities accomplish this goal.  So unless a site has demonstrated significant irritation, even if there's low desire, if it increases participation, then it's met the original goal.  By making it opt-in you reduce the participation by default.

Comment: OK, both comments from you above are valid points (why not integrate them also in your answer?). But I keep having a problem with the current implementation of the whole thing. As I summarized in my bold phrase of my question ... (the marketeers part of it is only like a related argument to take into consideration for evaluating if it should be opt-in or opt-out). Assume nothing gets changed by XMAS 2016, I'll for sure remember to use the SO-site to not-opt-in-by-default (or whatever I should call it) ...  Hoping drupal.SE will then not force me anymore "to turn it off".

Answer (score 1):

> Consider changing the logic behind "I hate hats" to an implementation with some logic to express something like "Count me in"

There is already. You have to click *I love hats* before you hate them. (This seems to be only true on Stack Overflow. I guess due to the large community over there. Why not implement this SE wide? Then everybody has the ability to opt-in)

[image: I love hats]

> you could use such "opt in" as a way to get your very first hat!

That is an idea for next year. There is already a badge that everybody gets, so that one could be reassigned to this action, I think this is a nice feature.

Comment: I think that's only for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Why? Don't other site have that?

Comment: I don't know about SO, but $elsewhere the default (if the site is participating) is to enable hats. I see this but that's because I opted-out and apparently 'hate hats'.

Comment: "You can opt out of the event by clicking on the snowflake icon in the top bar—Winter Bash notification to the right of the standard notifications, inactive—and then the "I hate hats" link at the bottom left of the box that pops up. (**NB: the reverse is true on Stack Overflow; fans of hats on SO will have to go through the same procedure but click a link to opt in at the end.**)". [Source](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/12/announcing-winter-bash-2015/)

Comment: @SimonKlaver : thank you very much for pointing this out. I think you should convert your comment to an extra answer ...